# How can I view Pdf in flutter from firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, pdf, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to have a button so that when i click, it can retrieve my pdf in firebase and view on the flutter application. I've only been seeing examples for assets/url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this package [pdf_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_flutter).

Example:-

```
PDF.network(
            'your firebase pdf url',
            height: 500,
            width: 300,
    )
```

let me know if it work for you.